# Obtener el valor de aria-label usando un elemento

Tags: javascript, amp, disqus

Estoy configurando los comentarios de Disqus en mi blog, pero tengo algunos problemas con las plantillas AMP.

Para configurar Disqus necesito un objeto que tiene dos variables que lleno usando Django, así:

```
var disqus_config = function () {
  this.page.url = '{{ config.SITEURL }}{{ article.get_absolute_url }}';
  this.page.identifier = '{{ article.idx }}'; 
};
```

esto se convierte en esto:

```
var disqus_config = function () {
  this.page.url = 'http://localhost:8000/desarrollo/agrupar-resultados-con-mysql/';
  this.page.identifier = 'd09a0882-74a2-4d66-97d8-63e37172a1b4';
};
```

Me interesa especialmente el contenido de `this.page.identifier`.

Ahora bien, para implementar Disqus en AMP debo colocar una página en otro dominio. Esta página tiene un script que carga los comentarios de Disqus, y que tiene exactamente las mismas configuraciones.

Mi problema es que en ese servidor *no tengo acceso a las variables de Django*, por lo tanto debo acceder a esos valores por JavaScript.

La URL del AMP terminan con... `amp`, así: `http://localhost:8000/desarrollo/agrupar-resultados-con-mysql/amp/`, entonces para obtener el valor de `this.page.url` **que debe ser la URL canónica** hago esto:

```
this.page.url = window.location.href.slice(0,-4);
```

...y funciona, porque veo el valor esperado en la consola.

#### Problema

Pero no sé como obtener el valor de `this.page.identifier`, así que se me ocurrió lo siguiente.

Tengo en mi plantilla un elemento `main` que es único y ahí voy a colocar el UUID en una cosa que se llama `aria-label`, así:

```
<main id="content" role="main" class="" aria-label="{{ article.idx }}">
```

... que se tranforma en

```
<main id="content" role="main" class="" aria-label="d09a0882-74a2-4d66-97d8-63e37172a1b4">
```

**Nota:** No tengo ninguna razón para usar `aria-label`, me parece que no interfiere con nada en la página y el validador de AMP no se queja.

Ahora en mi script externo, hago esto:

```
var disqus_config = function () {
  this.page.url = window.location.href.slice(0,-4);
  this.page.identifier =  // NO HAGO NADA PORQUE NO SÉ QUE HACER
};
```

Con `this.page.url` no tengo problemas, pero no sé **como obtener el valor almacenado en `aria-label`**. Bueno, ni siquiera sé si sea el mejor lugar para almacenar ese valor.

Puedo ubicar el elemento pero por su `id`: `idx = document.getElementById("content")`, y veo esto *todo*, absolutamente todo lo que está entre las marcas `<main>` y `</main>`. Pero yo solo quiero el valor de `aria-label`.

### Pregunta

Cómo puedo almacenar un valor tipo `d09a0882-74a2-4d66-97d8-63e37172a1b4` y cómo puedo recuperarlo con un script usando únicamente JavaScript en el navegador.

**Nota:** No puedo usar jQuery, solo JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si recuperas el elmentado usando usando el **getElementById** puedes obtener el valor del atributo con:

```
document.getElementById('content').attributes["aria-label"].value
```

Pero el atributo "aria-label" no es el mas adecuado para guardar este tipo de información. Seria mejor (si te lo permite el validador) que usaras un atributo llamado **data-idx**:

```
<main id="content" role="main" class="" data-idx="{{ article.idx }}">
```

Y lo recuperaras con:

```
document.getElementById('content').attributes["data-idx"].value
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, creo que mi problema tiene que ver con CORS... veré si la borro y la expongo de nuevo. Gracias.